# Is it possible that a google cloud compute VM or the cloud platform blocks the connections after the first time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, connection, google-compute-engine

**Situation**

I have a Spring boot Java backend application that I want to serve using the Google cloud platform. I created a VM instance with `Debian 9 Stretch`, installed the default-JRE package (`OpenJDK8`) and uploaded the runnable war-file. Running the application should build *two connections to two different external websites*.

Locally all works perfectly fine.

**Problem**

When I run the `war` for the first time on the VM (`java -jar app.war;` I also tried installing and deploying on tomcat), it runs just as expected. However, after the first time, building the connections hangs (but **no** exception is thrown). The rest of the application works fine. The only way I can get it to work again is removing the VM and do everything all over again.

Is it possible that the VM or the cloud platform blocks the connections after the first time? Can anyone help me analyze this problem?

If more information is needed, please let me know...

Comment: 1) That is unlikely to be the problem (IMO).  2) Possibly.  However, diagnosing networking problems at a distance is difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any suggestions how to locate the problem? I think it's unlikely that it's the application or java related, because (as I mentioned) locally all works fine every time... I'm a bit lost in where to search next :'( Could it be a process on the VM that hangs or isn't properly cleaned or whatever?

Comment: Look for a firewall problem or broken network configs within the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Cloud Platform does not block based on a number of connections. All network traffic is allowed or denied based on firewall rules and routes. There are some ports (such as port 25 for egress traffic) that are blocked and are outside of your control and some routes that are not visible.

However, what you are experiencing would not be caused by anything on the Google Cloud Platform level. Since you can connect at least once, this implies the firewall rules and routes are configured correctly.

This is possibly something with how the OS is configured which is refusing the second connection.

Comment: Still don't know what the cause of the problem was, but it seems it is debian related. On both debian and ubuntu the problem occurs. On a Red Hat VM the problem doesn't occur, so I'm switching to red hat I suppose.... Still frustrating I can't find the root cause though.

Answer (score 0):

1)To rule out any firewall issues, create another VM in the same-subnet and open all default internal. Curl the application on the VM. 
2)To understand whats going on the VM (Spin up a small war file hello world and see if this depicts the same behavior)
3)Looks for logs in the Stackdriver